# How to get interpolation in ggplot2 R line chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, logarithm, r-plotly, line-plot

I have the following dataframe

```
df1 <- data.frame(
    "A" = c(1:10), 
    "B" = seq(2, 10, by = 2)
)
df1$C = c('a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b','c','a','c','b')
```

I am now creating a plot with ggplot2

```
C <- ggplot(data = df1, mapping = aes(x = df1$A, y = df1$B, color = df1$C)) +
    geom_line() + 
    scale_x_continuous(trans = "log10") +
    scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log10')

C <- ggplotly(C, dynamicTicks = T)
C
```

When I Run C, the plot renders and I can read the plot values which display by hovering the mouse over the vertices. However, I am unable to see the values along the line where intrapolation has occurred. can this be achieved. And Is it possible to change the pattern of the graph to a logarithmic graph paper. Request someone to help.

Comment: Don't use `$` subsetting in `aes`; just use the bare variable name, here `aes(A, B, color = C)`. And the grid is logged; you just can't see it much because the numbers don't go very high.

Comment: I have tried this previously and am afraid it doesnt help.

Comment: That's not the solution, that's just to keep you from getting into trouble. The solution is to interpolate your own points before plotting.